# ConnectableObservable not emitting values

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactive

I am trying to understand hotObservables and have written this example but it doesn't seem to emitting anything.

```
    ConnectableObservable<Long> cold = Observable.intervalRange(1, 20, 100, 100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS).publish();
    cold.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("First: " + i));
    cold.connect();
```

Moving the `cold.connect()` to just after creating the `ConnectableObservable` doesn't changes anything.

Comment: If you are running this from the Java `main()` method, it may quit before the Observable has any chance of emitting from the background thread.

Comment: yes I was calling it from the Java main() method. I get it now.