# RxJava simple demo not work

Tags: rx-java

I just learned RxJava and find it's very useful,but when i start to test some code myself, I find it not work correctly.

I write some code like this,but it's do not print anything.The program stop immediately after the start.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) 
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) 
        .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer number) {
              System.out.println(number);
            }
        });
    }
```

and i also find it's only work in main thread.
This code will print number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()) 
        .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()) 
        .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer number) {
              System.out.println(number);
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm using rxjava 1.3.0 and i write this code follow the instruction from a article.

Did i missing something?

(I understand it now,it's looks like the rxjava will not create new thread immediately,so before rxjava can create new thread the main thread will be exited,and the jvm will be shutdown.

To make previous example work,just make main thread live longer.

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // 
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // 
        .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer number) {
              System.out.println(number);
            }
        });


        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

)

Comment: It looks good for me. Can you try it without `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`?

Comment: It work without subscribeOn and observeOn,but that was same as the second one,how can i run it in different thread?

Comment: The observable does not block (executed on subscribeOn). Therefore the main method will be exited and the JVM will shutdown. You need to use a blocking operation in the end. Use a blocking get or blocking subscribe method. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991778/connectableobservable-not-emitting-values

Comment: Wow,you are right,I actually forgot this,thank you very much

Comment: Your explanation why the main method exits is not true. Actuelly the main method is exited because the Observable code runs on another Thread. Therefore the observable subscription callback is not blocking the main method. It just takes some time for init. the thread and scheduling the task. Whil this is happening, the main method is already finished and the jvm will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Observable.toBlocking().subscribe()` instead of `Observable.subscribe()`.

Once you subscribed on the `Observable`, main thread exit. While rx worker theread is deamon thread by default, JVM will exit. So what you need to do is let main thread wait for the `Subscription` done.